# Git - creating repository with gitignore

Tags: git, repository, gitignore

Every time I set up new project I have the same problem, but now It's time to do this right.

In my .gitignore I have paths like this:

/assets/css/*

/assets/images/*

/assets/js/*

/system/cache/*

...etc.

Now when creating and pushing to repository those paths are missing, so for example, there is no images, css, js folder in repository and when I pull the repository from other computer those files/folders are missing and the system doesn't work.

I would like to achive that those paths are on repository but it's files are ignored.

Any suggestion on how to start this repository would be more than welcome.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As [Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F) answers,

> Currently the design of the Git index (staging area) only permits files to be listed, and nobody competent enough to make the change to allow empty directories has cared enough about this situation to remedy it.
>
> Directories are added automatically when adding files inside them. That is, directories never have to be added to the repository, and are not tracked on their own.

The only way is to create a empty file `.keep` just meant for adding the directory in Git staging area. This trick is used by [Rails too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928581/random-concerns-folders-and-keep-files).

Comment: Afaik `.gitkeep` is the name commonly used. But in the end it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I would achieve this by adding an empty hidden file in the directories.
Like ".path" and in the gןt ignore file specify the file extensions that you want to ignore in those paths.
For example:

```
/assets/img/*.jpg
```

That way you add the .path file witch is actually nothing and all the rest is ignored.

Let me know if it solves your issue.

Just remember that git is tracking content. Not directories. So keep that in mind when you want paths to be "tracked"